# Is it possible to ignore a specific error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want errors but I don't want this specific error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Is it possible I can get all errors except this one?
My current code is:

```
              if (json.data[0].price < '99') {
              //do something
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
          })
```

I forgot to mention this but my code is inside a fetch block. Is there any way I can do if error is this then ignore and continue

Comment: Fix the code. That error is worse than the error message - all the code after that error **WILL NOT BE EXECUTED**. Are you OK with the rest of the code being skipped? I mean, not just the `if` block but even code outside the `if` block before the `.catch()`

Comment: What do you mean by "get all errors"? Do you mean log all errors except that one? Use an `if` statement.

Comment: @Hetric Monkey Im not sure how I would format it

Comment: I am kinda new to node.js

Comment: And the fix isn't even hard `if (json.data && json.data[0] && json.data[0].price < '99') ...` or if your interpreter supports optional chaining `if (json.data?.[0]?.price < '99') ...`

Comment: Try if(json.data?.[0]?.price < 99)

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in `try-catch` block and since you have `catch` block at the end, it will handle all the errors

```
try{
  if (json.data[0].price < '99') {
    //do something
  }
}catch(err) throw err
```

or you can simply check if length is greater than 0 or not

```
if (json.data && json.data.length>0 && json.data[0].price < '99') {
        //do something
      }
```

Your choice should depend on the operations you want to perform.

Comment: this doesnt work, I think it is because it is because my code is inside a fetch block, I am only looking for things under "99" but there is ratelimits with the api i use so thats why it errors as no data in [0] because the only response to the ratelimit is "you're making too many requests"

Comment: @cooldevnocap - I didn't write this answer, but this answers the question you asked.  If you have other problems also, then those are not in your question and there's no way you can expect answers here to know anything about those other problems.  Those other problems might belong in a different question.  This answers what you asked.